# Images won’t load on mobile but will load on Desktop browsers

Tags: html, css, reactjs

My react weather app suddenly stopped displaying images from OpenWeather on mobile. The weekly forecast and the currently forecast images display white borders instead of images on mobile. The website works perfectly on desktop. I have zero clue why.

Code that gens the weekly weather.

```
  <div className="weekly">
    {
      weatherData.data.daily.map((item, index) => {
        // console.log(item)
        if (index > 0) {
          return (
            <div className="weekly-item" key={index}>
                <span className="item-day">
                  {moment(moment.unix(item.dt)).local().format('ddd')}
                </span>
                <span className="item-icon">
                  <img
                    src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${item.weather[0].icon}.png`}
                    className="forecast-icon"
                    alt="Weather forecast"
                  />
                </span>
                <br />
                <div className="min-max">
                  <span className="item-max">
                    {Math.round(item.temp.max)}&deg;
                  </span>
                  <span className="item-min">{Math.round(item.temp.min)}&deg;</span>
                </div>
            </div>
          )
        }
      })
    }
  </div>
```

My site:
https://weather-mee.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? It is working on mobile DevTools.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I’ve just tried it on 3 different mobile browsers and a colleagues phone as well. Could this be a bug?